# HAProxy routing, without hard path

Tags: routes, haproxy

I want to catch and route a call based on URL/admin, but the backend doesn't respond to /admin, rather at /. How can I do this? Below will send the call to someaddress.com:80/admin when I need it to ignore the admin and go to someaddress.com:80

```
acl url_admintool_ui path_beg /admin
use_backend admintool-ui-backend if url_admintool_ui

backend admintool-ui-backend
mode http
server admintool-ui someaddress.com:80
```

Answer (score 1):

The [reqrep](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4.2-reqirep) keyword should do the job.

```
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /admin(.*)     \1\ /\2 if url_admintool_ui
```

Comment: This does what I ask, thanks. I realize now though that I need it to just forward to the new address with a new URL and not under the current. Now it calls the new address with the current URL and the page fails to load.